# passing a php function a variable amount of parameters*

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is a php function:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", ...variable amount of parameters...);
```

It will accept a variable amount of parameters you can review the documentation here - [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_stmt_bind_param&scope=quickref).  Obviously I can't type in `$param1`, `$param2`, `$param3`... because I don't know many there will be. It is decided after run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `call_user_func_array()` is using a callback as its first parameter, you can use any function you want. For example:

```
php > echo date('r', time());
Mon, 12 Sep 2011 00:37:52 +0300
php > echo call_user_func_array('date', array('r', time()));
Mon, 12 Sep 2011 00:38:23 +0300
```

So, you can `call_user_func_array()` as follows:

```
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($statement, "s"), $params));
```

Comment: ok thanks i get it......you are the third...why in do they say "call_user" it threw me off completely...meaningfull names...there's an idea

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can use `call_user_func_array()` with any valid [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) - so that includes PHP functions;

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo(), empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print() or unset().

Comment: ok someone else said this but i did not believe them...why do they call it call_user_func_array()?  I'm trying not to learn by experiment...I'll give it a go.

Comment: Why are you trying *not* to learn by experiment?? That's the best way! "Hm.. what does this button do?" :)

Comment: well, b.c. i'm flying blind in php...no debugger...with js it's easy use built in tools...w/ php i have to link into my class hierarchy with test .php files...it is difficult

Answer (score 1):

[`func_get_args();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: You can replace the question mark with an example, this is the solution. One-liner answers are OK but not great.